# Haskell map a given function over the elements at the leaves of a GTree

Tags: haskell

I got a data structure:

```
data GTree a = Leaf a | Gnode [GTree a]
```

and an example of this map function for different data structure:

```
data Tree a = Nil | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Read)

mapTree :: (a-> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
mapTree Nil = Nil
mapTree f (Node x t1 t2) = Node (f x) (mapTree f t1) (mapTree f t2)
```

I need to write this function for my GTree data structure, but I can't make it.. For now I have this kind of function:

```
mapTree :: (a -> b) -> GTree a -> GTree b
mapTree f (Gnode [a]) = Gnode [mapTree f a]
mapTree f (Leaf a) = Leaf f
```

Can someone please help me finish it? Or at least explain me how to implement..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there! You've forgotten to handle the case where there's more than one element in the list of subtrees. The pattern `[x]` stands for a *single-element* list.

I'm going to match an arbitrarily long (or short) list of subtrees `ts` and then use `map` to apply a recursive call to each of them.

```
mapTree :: (a -> b) -> GTree a -> GTree b
mapTree f (Gnode ts) = Gnode (map (mapTree f) ts)
mapTree f (Leaf x) = Leaf (f x)
```

NB. I know this is an exercise, but in production code I'd ask GHC to write this function for me using the `DeriveFunctor` language extension.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data GTree a = Leaf a | Gnode [GTree a] deriving Functor

mapTree :: (a -> b) -> GTree a -> GTree b
mapTree = fmap
```